# Composite design pattern parenting components

Tags: design-patterns, composite

I've found that having composite pattern there is one thing that can be solved different ways: the parenting to the other composite.

What I mean is that if the "child" element should know about the "parent" element this can be done in two ways :

- by putting the parent element to the constructor:

  ```
  Composite (Composite parent) {
     parent.addChild(this);
     this.parent = parent;
  }

   public void addChild(Composite child) {
      children.add(child);
   }
  ```
- by using the addChild method which internally assigns a reference of itself to the added child:

  ```
  public void addChild(Composite child) {
      children.add(child);
      child.setParent(this);
  }
  ```

Now, my problem is which method to use? Which one is more reliable, more flexible and less error prone? Is there anybody who experienced both and decided to choose one of this methods?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

> Composite pattern can be used when clients should ignore the difference
>   between compositions of objects and individual objects.

Since the idea is to treat a group of objects as a single one (of the same type), usually the composite object iterates through its group (of children) in order to propagate the same behavior. Keeping a list of children in the parent makes more sense from this aspect.

**Update**: I misunderstood your question. Let me try again: Usually the composite object keeps reference to its children, for the reason above. The parent link might (or not) be excess. Why do you want to keep a reference to the parent? Is there a shared state between the children?

**Update 2**: Allright, the parent link should be there. In this case, both ways you mention are functionally equivalent and this is essentially an API design question. A TDD-ish way of thinking could help you here. For example, since the scenegraph is essentially a tree, a simple scenario can be creating the first nodes. This is how you'd do it in both versions (as I understand):

```
// First way:
// Shorter but still readable. Parent relationship established at construction, so you can count on that the parent property is always at its final state.
Composite root = new Composite(null);
Composite child = new Composite(root);

// Second way:
// Has an extra statement but more explicit. Also slightly more flexible since the parent relationship can be established _after_ construction. 
Composite root = new Composite();
Composite child = new Composite();
root.addChild(child);
```

Maybe re-parenting a node might be another interesting test, if you have that kind of a requirement. Determining your most important operations and designing for them will shape the API in the most appropriate way.

Comment: Yes I know... but I've forgot to add the child to the list of children in the constructor... will fix it in a second.

Comment: Actually I didn't mean that. But now I see that I misunderstood your question.

Comment: There might be many reasons to preserve the link to parent element. In my case, I'm developing GUI library and 3D scene graph. The child elements of GUI have to know what's parent clipping area so they dont go out of parent bounds. For the scenegraph - it's for creating nested transforms - when parent object rotates - the child object rotates with the parent so the parent current tranformation has to be known.

Comment: I understand composite design pattern, and you actually duplicated the code from the question. Actually you made me think a little. I don't know what TDD stands for but if you talk about Test Driven Design - there is no point we can get to in the discussion, as TTD is not about semantics at it's core. What I'm asking for is an examples of scenarios in which things can become issue or, the other - way they can ease all the pains and make code really good. Take a look for example at Swing and SWT - SWT takes parents in constructors while Swing uses "addChild" method. My question is "why"?

Comment: I think you miss the point. You ask: "Which one is more reliable, more flexible and less error prone?", and my answer is _it depends_. I added my comparison as comments in the code but we don't know your exact requirements, so my suggestion is to test it out yourself with your own scenarios which will then shape your design. TDD here stands for test driven development. It helps design an API in a sufficiently minimal way, and that's pretty related to semantics IMO. The code above is the _usage_ examples of APIs you mentioned in this sense, not duplicates.

Comment: I think your last line (about SWT and Swing) can help you better as a question. (Note: Winforms also uses the addChild-approach.)

Comment: Everything depends, but what are the factors? It's not an answer to say that something depends. I know the client code looks differently but that's nothing.  What are the complete scenarios where one solution is better than other in the long run? About Swing and SWT there I see no answer, they are both GUI libraries. This is a general question: "why to favor one method over the other". I've considered the "addChild" method to be better because of not doing work in constructor for example and gives higher flexiblity. There might be more in-depth details about each of these solutions.

Comment: Your question is generic and so is my answer. If you need domain-specific advice, your question must reflect that.